# Convert Latitude and Longitude to magnetic variation

Tags: objective-c, geospatial, latitude-longitude

How can I convert latitude and longitude into magnetic variation for an IOS app (Objective C). I am looking for a simple solution I can incorporate in an app.

I willing to trade off precision and handling all possible cases for simplicity.

Comment: There is no magic conversion from latitude/longitude to magnetic variation. It is different everywhere on earth, and not in a formulaic way. That is why magnetic variation mystified even the most scientifically careful navigators for centuries. You can convert between true north and magnetic north, but that is not at all the same thing: magnetic variation is _how the compass points_, which is a purely local phenomenon.

Comment: Depends how close you want to be.  You could take a set of points and fit a curve to it with regression. If you luck out you might approach 50% of the actual variation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I got several possible from different sources. Unfortunately, the overzapping SO Rectal Sphincters got to the this question, so someone else will have to ask to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would be to have a stored table and interpolate your current position.  I don't think you'll find a simple formula, but it doesn't change quickly with position.